# Unable to import WebRTCAdaptor which is in js file from antmedia package in node modules folder in angular ts file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ant-media-server-sdk

It is showing an error that :

```
Could not find a declaration file for the module 
'@antmedia/webrtc_adaptor/js/webrtc_adaptor.js'. 
'D:/web/node_modules/@antmedia/webrtc_adaptor/js/webrtc_adaptor.js' 
implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/antmedia__webrtc_adaptor` 
if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing 
`declare module '@antmedia/webrtc_adaptor/js/webrtc_adaptor.js';`
```

Reference Image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKQdR.png

[image: Error]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error is self-explanatory.

In order to resolve your issue what you have to do is to create a folder named "antmedia__webrtc_adaptor" at the below path and create a file named "index.d.ts"

Inside the index.d.ts file you have to put the below code and save it.

inside index.d.ts paste the code `declare module '@antmedia/webrtc_adaptor'`

node_modules/@types/**antmedia__webrtc_adaptor**/index.d.ts

Answer (score 0):

The fix is apparently to import it like this for TypeScript support:

```
import { WebRTCAdaptor } from '@antmedia/webrtc_adaptor/dist/es';
```

The TypeScript hints are, however at the moment in a rather sad state: https://github.com/ant-media/Ant-Media-Server/issues/5066#issuecomment-1814299018